# Error code 1111: says invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to use
select Suppliers.sid
from Suppliers
left join Catalog on Suppliers.sid=Catalog.sid
where Catalog.cost>avg(Catalog.cost);
but im getting error code 1111:
Unsure what's going on with my database. Im very nice to sql and just having issues getting this to work.

```
    CREATE DATABASE CSC123Lab2;
USE CSC123Lab2;

CREATE TABLE Suppliers (
sid CHAR(20),
sname CHAR(20),
address CHAR(20),
pid CHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Parts (
pid CHAR(20),
pname CHAR(20),
color CHAR(20),
sid CHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Catalog (
sid CHAR(20),
pid CHAR(20),
cost REAL
);

ALTER TABLE Suppliers ADD PRIMARY KEY (sid);
ALTER TABLE Parts ADD PRIMARY KEY (pid);

INSERT INTO Suppliers (sid, sname, address) VALUES (1, "carvel", "1234 Main Street");
INSERT INTO Suppliers (sid, sname, address) VALUES (2, "coldstone", "5678 Pine Street");
INSERT INTO Suppliers (sid, sname, address) VALUES (3, "ralphs", "9876 Oak Street");
INSERT INTO Suppliers (sid, sname, address) VALUES (4, "Acme Widget", "4321 Maple Street");

INSERT INTO Parts (pid, pname, color) VALUES (1, "hammer", "red");
INSERT INTO Parts (pid, pname, color) VALUES (2, "screwdriver", "pink");
INSERT INTO Parts (pid, pname, color) VALUES (3, "nails", "green");
INSERT INTO Parts (pid, pname, color) VALUES (4, "screws", "teal");

INSERT INTO Catalog (sid, pid, cost) VALUES (1, 3, 32);
INSERT INTO Catalog (sid, pid, cost) VALUES (4, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO Catalog (sid, pid, cost) VALUES (4, 3, 48);
INSERT INTO Catalog (sid, pid, cost) VALUES (2, 4, 24);

select Suppliers.sid
from Suppliers 
left join Catalog on Suppliers.sid=Catalog.sid
where Catalog.cost>avg(Catalog.cost);


DROP TABLE Catalog;
DROP TABLE Parts;
DROP TABLE Suppliers;
DROP DATABASE CSC123Lab2;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your sample code is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

use group by and do filter in next level

```
with cte  as 
(select Suppliers.sid,avg(Catalog.cost) as avg_val
from Suppliers 
left join Catalog on Suppliers.sid=Catalog.sid
group by Suppliers.sid
) select a.sid
from Catalog a join cte on a.sid=cte.sid
where a.cost>avg_val
```

Comment: When i use that im getting error code: 1054. unknown column 'catalog.cost' in 'having clause'

Comment: @Timothy https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b26d6f5cc7a39fc9bbec85a81b690a6

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=468eae2ae79996951fb810fe54c5d901 Posted my exact code i have. Getting error under "with" saying it is not valid at this position for this server version and Duplicate entry for "1" for key in "Primary"

Comment: change string qute from double to single  like "" to '' and you dont need to create database in dbfiddle just create table and insert data with your projection query

Comment: Where would I need to change that because with is still saying its not valid at this position. Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte  as  (select Suppliers.sid,avg(Catalog.cost) as avg_val from Suppliers  left' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you just want a window function:

```
select s.sid
from Suppliers s join
     (select c.*, avg(c.cost) over () as avg_cost
      from Catalog c
     ) c
     on s.sid = c.sid
where c.cost > c.avg_cost;
```

Note, though, that you don't really need the `left join`.  The `where` clause turns the left join into an `inner join`.

Then, you don't need the `join` at all, because `sid` is in both tables:

```
select c.sid
from (select c.*, avg(c.cost) over () as avg_cost
      from Catalog c
     ) c
where c.cost > c.avg_cost;
```

If you prefer, you could express this using a subquery:

```
select c.sid
from Catalog c
where c.cost > (select avg(c2.cost) from catalog c2);
```

Comment: I tried adding that but im getting Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() as avg_cost       from Catalog c      ) c where c.cost > c.avg_cost' at line 2

Comment: @Timothy . . . Try the last version.  You are using an old version of MySQL that doesn't support window functions.

Comment: okay that seemed to work. i got sid 1 and 4. im also having an issue with this question For every supplier that supplies a green part and a red part, print the name and price of the most expensive part that she supplies. Ive tried doing select Parts.pname, Catalog.cost
from ((Suppliers
inner join Catalog on suppliers.sid=Catalog.sid)
inner join Parts on Catalog.pid=Parts.pid)
where Parts.color='green'and'red';  but im getting only the the table that says pname and cost but its not showing the name and price part. Just says pname and cost

Comment: @Timothy . . . You have multiple answers to the question asked here.  You should accept one of the answers and if you have another question, ask it as another question.